# 2 Radio Buttons in different group boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, radio-button, conditional-statements

I have 2 radio buttons in different group boxes.

[image: screenshot of design]

If payment method (rButtonCredit) and duration (rButton24Months) are checked show $ amount in Total Discount text box.

I've tried numerous things and I can only get $5.00 discount show in textbox instead of $5.25.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
        if (rButton24Months.Checked)
        {
            textBoxDuration.Text = "-$5.00";
        }
        if (rButton24Months.Checked)
        {
            textBoxDiscount.Text = "$5.00";
        }
        else if (rButton24Months.Checked || rButtonCredit.Checked)
        {
            textBoxDiscount.Text = "$5.25";
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you have more than one GroupBox and each GroupBox has 2 RadioButtons (so you have to show in TextBoxes the results of User choices in each GroupBox separately), or do you have 2 RadioButtons in total, hence just two TextBoxes?  Clarify your setup (an image of the layout wouldn't hurt)-- BTW, it look like you want CheckBoxes, not RadioButtons. -- The the first two `if` blocks evaluate the same condition, the last one appears to want an `&`.

Comment: I do have more than one Group Box. 'rButton24Months' is in one group box with 2 other RadioButtons. 'rButtonCredit' is in another Group Box with 1 other RadioButton.

Comment: RadioButtons that belong together must go into __one__ GrouipBox only, not only for them to work properly but also to avoid __surpising users__!

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this way.

**step 1:**

First you are naming both `RadioButtons`.

**step 2:**

You are binding both `CheckedChanged` events to the same method. `CheckedChanged+=checked;`

**step 3:**

Enjoy If you found it useful. Make a USEFUL

```
int str;
      public void checked(object sender, EventsArgs e)
      {
          
          var btn = (RadioButton)sender;
          if(btn.name == "first")
          {
              if(btn.checked ==true)
              {
                  str+=5;
              }
              else
              {
                  str-+(-5);
              }
          }
          if(btn.name == "second")
          {
              if(btn.checked ==true)
              {
                  str+=2;
              }
              else
              {
                  str-+(-2);
              }
          }
```